# Completing CSS changes if transition is interrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, transition

http://a.pomf.se/hjhsav.webm

I am making a menu where the arrow keys move the whole UI left or right.

Javascript:

```
$('.xmb').css('left','+=175px')
```

CSS:

```
.xmb{
position: relative;
top: 240px;
left: 310px;
transition: left .2s;}
```

The issue is that if I hammer the arrow keys, or hold one down, the transition is triggered again before it can complete, and is interrupted. It subsequently fails to move the 175px (per arrow key press) and the menu becomes out of place. I tried using jQuery animations but the result was even worse (the animations were uninterrupted and therefore lagged way behind where the menu should have been. I could hammer the arrow keys alternatively and then let go and the menu would move left and right for a few seconds longer. It also didn't move the menu by the same amount as the CSS transition for some bizzare reason.)

Is there a simple way to just make the transition jump to its final position in the event where it is interrupted? If I hit the left arrow key 3 times in less than .2 seconds, I want it to move 3*175px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one step you can check if left is 0 and then move it.

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.xmb').css('left')=="0px"){
        $('.xmb').css('left','+=175px');
    }
})
```

if you have more than one steps you can use the modulus operator and move only if result is 0

[Modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9f59bza0%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(parseInt($('.xmb').css('left')) % 175==0){
        $('.xmb').css('left','+=175px');
    }
})
```

If you need to remove the transition when you have a second click or keypress you have to create a seperate class for transition and add/remove when you need it.
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd668a10/1/)

Comment: That would only move it if it had completed the transition though, right? I want it to be snappy with the arrow key presses. If I hit left and then hit left again (within 0.2 seconds), I want it to skip the rest of the first transition (and complete the movement of 175px) and start the next transition immediately.

Comment: Try this fiddle pls and test it with your code. Its not the greatest solution but i think it works. 
https://jsfiddle.net/qd668a10/1/

I also corrected some errors from the code before

Comment: Wait, no. Now it's broken in a different way. If I hammer left and right, it can become offset by 175px (roughly), as if it skips one of the keypresses altogether.